# NSMenuItem with action added to NSStatusBar is grayed out when the selected function is moved to other class

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

If the function that is being called as the NSMenuItem action isn't located in AppDelegate the menu entry is grayed out.

I can't seem to figure out what exactly seems to go wrong... Maybe I'm initialising the StatusBarItemController wrong? As soon as I move the printToTheWalls to the AppDelegate class it starts to work.

```swift
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var statusBarItemController: StatusBarItemController?
    let statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.squareLength)

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
        statusBarItemController = StatusBarItemController()
        if let button = statusBarItem.button {
            button.image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("trayIcon"))
        }
        statusBarItemController?.constructMenu(with: statusBarItem)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

}
```

```swift
import Cocoa

class StatusBarItemController {

    func constructMenu(with statusBarItem: NSStatusItem) {
        let menu = NSMenu()
        menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(
            title: "From the windows...",
            action: #selector(printToTheWalls(_:)),
            keyEquivalent: ""
        ))
        menu.addItem(NSMenuItem.separator())
        menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(
            title: "Quit",
            action: #selector(NSApplication.terminate(_:)),
            keyEquivalent: "q"
        ))

        statusBarItem.menu = menu
    }

    @objc func printToTheWalls(_ sender: NSMenuItem) {
        //This doesn't seem to be called and/or found
        print("To the Walls!")
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the benefit of this extra class? You have to set the `target` of the action accordingly.

Comment: You'll need to make StatusBarItemController derive from NSObject, I think. Otherwise it cannot be introspected for validation of menu items.

Comment: @vadian It's purely for organising my code

Comment: @matt I changed `class StatusBarItemController` to `class StatusBarItemController: NSObject` but this doesn't change the behaviour

Comment: Well perhaps you should put the code back where it was. Menu item validation is a complicated business and relies upon your code being in certain places.

Comment: @matt I'm ready to accept that this code can only reside in the AppDelegate file but I would really like to know why it **has** to be there

Comment: I think I've told you my theory twice already. Might want to read https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/EnablingMenuItems.html

Comment: @matt Thanks for the interesting link. Sadly it doesn't help me solve my problem or answer my question as the why it has to be in the AppDelegate file to work at all.

Comment: Well I think it's because of how the responder chain is constructed.

Comment: It doesn't have to be in the AppDelegate - as vadian has already commented, set the NSMenuItem's target to whatever class has the delegate method.

Comment: @red_menace Thanks your comment made me understand vadian 's comment fully and this worked (set it to 'self'). If you would like to type out an answer I would love to mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to manually set the target property to `self` as @vadian and @red_menace helped me discover in the comments of the question.

The working code looks like this:

```swift
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var statusBarItemController: StatusBarItemController?

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
        statusBarItemController = StatusBarItemController()
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

}
```

```swift
import Cocoa

class StatusBarItemController: NSObject {
    let statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.squareLength)

    override init() {
        super.init()
        if let button = statusBarItem.button {
            button.image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("trayIcon"))
        }
        constructMenu()
    }

    func constructMenu() {
        if let button = statusBarItem.button {
            button.image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("trayIcon"))
        }
        let menu = NSMenu()

        let fromTheWindowsItem = NSMenuItem(
            title: "From the windows...",
            action: #selector(StatusBarItemController.printToTheWalls(_:)),
            keyEquivalent: ""
        )
        fromTheWindowsItem.target = self
        menu.addItem(fromTheWindowsItem)
        menu.addItem(NSMenuItem.separator())
        menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(
            title: "Quit",
            action: #selector(NSApplication.terminate(_:)),
            keyEquivalent: "q"
        ))

        statusBarItem.menu = menu
    }

    @objc func printToTheWalls(_ sender: NSMenuItem) {
        print("To the Walls!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea why the target didn't need setting in `AppDelegate`?

Comment: I had to set the target for the individual NSMenuItems to the entity that will handle the action. In this case StatusBarItemController