# Swift: Try to use closure instead #selector but not working

Tags: swift, cocoa, closures

I'm trying to use a closure instead selector but it does not work. The print does not work can you help me

My custom Action:

```
final class Action: NSObject {

    private let _action: () -> ()

    init(action: @escaping () -> ()) {
        _action = action
        super.init()
    }

    @objc func action() {
        _action()
    }

}
```

Using:

```
let menu = NSMenu()

let action = Action { print("My action") }
menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Delete", action: #selector(action.action), keyEquivalent: ""))

tableView.menu = menu
```

When I click on the menu, the delete option does not print, why does not it work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSMenuItem with action added to NSStatusBar is grayed out when the selected function is moved to other class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55995415/nsmenuitem-with-action-added-to-nsstatusbar-is-grayed-out-when-the-selected-func)

Comment: No its no my question

Comment: Setting `target` of the menu item to `action` didn't work?

Comment: Not working with taget

Comment: Can you update with how you're setting target? The above code cannot work, because it doesn't assign a target for the menu item. Setting the target is a key step, so it's important that you show how you're doing that. Selectors are meaningless without a target (`action.action` doesn't mean "call `action.action`". It means "send the `-action` message to whatever the target is, and to help me make sure I'm doing it right, please check that my selector is something that exists on `Action`, which is the type of `action`").

Comment: Is `action` deallocated because it goes out of scope?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a target for the `NSMenuItem`. As per the Apple documentation, this doesn’t seem to be included in the initializer but can be set afterwards.

```
let menu = NSMenu()

let action = Action { print("My action") }
var menuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "Delete", action: #selector(action), keyEquivalent: "")
menuItem.target = action // This refers to the action instance
menu.addItem(menuItem)

tableView.menu = menu
```

Comment: @MickaelBelhassen Thsnks for checking it. I’m not at my computer and wrote this based on the documentation as I felt the problem was relating to the target for the selector. I’m out of ideas at this point.

Answer (score -2):

This is not possible because selectors are just names of methods, not methods themselves.

**BUT** there is another way to use a closure with **#selector**

```
/// Target-Action helper.
final class Action: NSObject {

    private let _action: () -> ()

    init(action: @escaping () -> ()) {
        _action = action
        super.init()
    }

    @objc func action() {
        _action()
    }

}

let action1 = Action { print("action1 triggered") }

let button = UIButton()
button.addTarget(action1, action: #selector(action1.action), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: I've tried this approach with an `NSMenuItem` but couldn't get it to work. At least you have to keep a reference to the `Action` object somewhere or it will get deallocated.