# StatusItem in MacOS menubar is greyed out and doesn't work

Tags: swift, macos

I have some Swift code that looks like this. However the menu item will just be greyed out and not work. I have tried different versions for the `#selector` on the item, but so far nothing works.

```swift
class StatusBarController {
    private var statusBar: NSStatusBar
    private var statusItem: NSStatusItem
    
    init() {
        statusBar = NSStatusBar.init()
        self.statusItem = statusBar.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
        

        self.state = FirebaseData()
        self.startUpdate()
        
        self.setupMenus()
        
    }
    
    func setupMenus() {
        let menu = NSMenu()

        menu.addItem(withTitle: "Play Pause", action: #selector(StatusBarController.onClickPlayPause), keyEquivalent: "1")

        menu.addItem(NSMenuItem.separator())

        menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Quit", action: #selector(NSApplication.terminate(_:)), keyEquivalent: "q"))

        self.statusItem.menu = menu
    }
    
    @objc func onClickPlayPause(sender : NSMenuItem) {
        if self.isRunning() {
            self.pause()
        } else if (self.state.intervalLeft != nil) {
            self.resume()
        } else {
            self.startTimer(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong here? Thank you!

[image: Play pause greyed out]

Comment: I've been following this tutorial: https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-make-macos-menu-bar-app/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSMenuItem with action added to NSStatusBar is grayed out when the selected function is moved to other class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55995415/nsmenuitem-with-action-added-to-nsstatusbar-is-grayed-out-when-the-selected-func)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the target.

```
let playMenuItem = menu.addItem(withTitle: "Play Pause", action: #selector(onClickPlayPause), keyEquivalent: "1")
playMenuItem.target = self
```

The `Quit` item works via First Responder.

Comment: Thank you! That was it. I don't have a good grasp yet about how these selectors/targets work.

Comment: And consider that the shortcuts work only if the application is frontmost. And add an underscore character in the method signature `@objc func onClickPlayPause(_ sender : NSMenuItem)`